# Make part of the text as link.(react - localization)

Tags: reactjs

I need to mark part of the text as a link. Something like:
"Please log in with your email...". This text must be localized later.
I need that "log in" part to be the link.

When I do something like this in the render method:

```
var link = React.DOM.a({
                    href: this.makeHref('login')
                },
                'log in'
            );// or React.createElement or
//var link = <a href={this.makeHref('login')}>
//   'log in'</a>;
<div>{'Please '+ link + ' with your email...'}</div>
```

It will output:

```
Please `[object Object]` with your email...
```

Without surround text, I receive the expected result. In other words: How to make react render HTML not object.

This is a simplified example - I need to insert link text with format marker `{0}` like in C# - or any other working solution.

Thank you for help!

Comment: You might want to look at Yahoo's library: https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl

Comment: Thank you for the link! For this simple situation as it figured out, i can use next code:        var text = Counterpart.translate(lc.).split('{0}');
  return <div>{text[0]} {link} {text[1]}</div>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to use an element within another element, just use curly braces like so:

```jsx
var Component = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var link = <a href={this.makeHref('login')}>log in</a>;

    return <div>Please {link} with your email.</div>;
  }
};
```

You can see a working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/jrunning/fencjn4x/

If you're going to be internationalizing your app at some point in the future I recommend a) crossing that bridge when you come to it, and b) using a solution like [React Intl](http://formatjs.io/react/) instead of trying to build your own solution with string concatenation.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not really that i need. As you can see i have in code example such syntax. With localization i don't know the place where link will be placed. Therefore i'm using format marker for link, and then in code it will be like: <div>{Counterpart.translate(lc.REGISTERED_USR).format(link)}</div>

Comment: It must replace marker with <a href...>log in</a>, but it seems like react element + string, invokes toString() method, instead of rendering

Comment: For this simple situation as it figured out, i can use next code: var text = Counterpart.translate(lc.REGISTERED_USR).split('{0}'); return <div>{text[0]} {link} {text[1]}</div>